# Get position of elements respect to parent with translate transform

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 floating divs (children) inside a container (parent). It acts like a slider, so on user action I slide from the first div to the second by updating the container (parent) css transform property to translate3d(-divwidth,0,0).

This works fine, but I also need to get the position of the elements inside the children div, and at the moment when grab it elements from both children div are being taken as being in the same position (even if only 1 of them is in the viewport, the other one is floating and not visible).

Is there a way of getting the position of the elements inside the divs relative to the parent, taking into account the transformation?

Thanks

Comment: Provide a [mcve], please.